# Applying a for loop on Out[]

Tags: output-formatting

I have a number of expressions, each one is an output: Out[135], Out[136], etc.
I wish to print all of these outputs in a C++ form using the function: CForm. I can apply it on each Out[] separately like so,

```
CForm[Out[135]]
```

I was trying to save time and create a for loop as follows:

```
For[i = 0, i = 34, i++, Out = Out[135 + i]; Print[CForm[Out]]]
```

But this didn't work!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
Do[Print[CForm[Out[135 + i]]], {i, 0, 34}];
```

Comment: This worked just perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways:

```
CForm[Out[#]]& /@ Range[135, 169]
```

and

```
Table[ CForm[Out[i]], {i, 135, 169}]
```

---

As the OP wants these printed out, instead of in lists, here are some alternatives. Both,

```
(* Note the semi-colons *)
Print[CForm[Out[#]]]& /@ Range[135, 169];
Table[Print[CForm[Out[i]]], {i, 135, 169}];
```

work, but [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scan.html) has no output by default, so this is superior

```
Scan[Print[CForm[Out[#]]]&, Range[135, 169]]
```

Comment: Both of them work. Thanks. But the expressions were separated by a comma (all grouped in one output), I have too many so this could be annoying. The answer by Alexey gives each expression as an output. But many thanks anyways :)

Comment: @stupidity right, both of my methods return lists. This can be overcome by the additions I made above.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 3):

While you have been given answers on how you can do it, nobody yet did tell you what you did wrong. There are actually several errors in your code.

The first error is the `i = 34`. Here are actually *two* errors. The first error is that you used an assignment where you actually wanted to do a comparison. Equality comparison is done with `==`, not `=`.

However, even if you replace `i = 34` with `i == 34`, the code will still not work. That's because the second argument is *not* the condition for ending the loop, but the condition for *continuing* the loop. So the for loop will assign `0` to `i`, then check `i == 34`, find it false, and immediately leave the loop. Therefore you'd have to write `i != 34` or `i < 34` at this point.

If you fix that, you'll notice an error message. That's coming from the assignment `Out = Out[135 + i]`. `Out` is protected and therefore cannot be assigned to. However let's assume it were not protected, what would happen? Well, let's assume `Out[135]` is `x`. Now that value would be assigned to `Out` (and then printed). Then in the next iteration, when coming across that assignment again, it would first evaluate `Out` to `x` on the right hand side of the assignment, and then proceed with the statement `Out = x[135+7]`, assigning x[136] to `Out`. Clearly not what you'd want.

To fix that last error, you should use another variable name, say `nextout = Out[135 + i]; Print[CForm[nextout]]` or even better, just don't use a variable at this point and just write `Print[CForm[Out[135 + i]]]`.

After fixing that error as well, the loop works as intended (but the `Do` loop suggested by Alexey Popkov is still the better alternative in this case).

Comment: Thank you indeed for showing me my mistakes and teaching me how to do it correctly. I'm a beginner with Mathematica, but I'm liking it exponentially with time! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `$Post = CForm`.

> [`$Post` is a global variable whose value, if set, is applied to every output expression.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Post.html)

Comment: I see. This is useful if I want all expressions in my notebook to be in CForm. Thanks

Comment: @stupidity I find the fact that you're using `Out` to store your expressions very confusing.  I suggest you don't.  I also suggest you set something reasonable like `$HistoryLength = 3` to conserve memory, unless that is never a problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the tips. I'm only a beginner. :D

Comment: @stupidity that's OK.  Take a look at [these resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7113954/618728) for help getting started.  Also see [Faysal's huge omnibus post of *Mathematica* resources.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/121)  Last but not least, take advantage of [the chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)